# How to optimize my query in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, query-optimization, performancecounter

When I run this query, it's taking **32 seconds**. This same query without changing anything it executes in **17 seconds** until yesterday.

Table information:

- `Item` table             =    158,117 records
- `Transaction` table      =  4,096,589 records
- `TransactionEntry` table = 70,165,678 records

I have created Index as well for those table in the following way

Index:

- For `Item` table = `ID, ItemLookupCode, SupplierID, ParentItem`
- For `Transaction` table = `Time, TransactionNumber, StoreID`
- For `TransactionEntry` table = `TransactionNumber, StoreID, Quantity, Price, Cost`

This is my query:

```
--Total Quantity
SELECT 
    items.ItemLookupCode,
    sum(transactionsEntry.Quantity) Quantity,
    sum(transactionsEntry.Quantity*transactionsEntry.Price) TotalPrice,
    sum(transactionsEntry.Cost*transactionsEntry.Quantity) as ExtendedCost
INTO
    ##temp_TotalQuantity
FROM
    (SELECT 
         TransactionNumber, StoreID, Time
     FROM 
         [HQMatajer].[dbo].[Transaction]
     WHERE 
         Time >= CONVERT(datetime, '2015-01-01 00:00:00', 102) 
         AND Time <= CONVERT(datetime, '2015-12-31 23:59:59', 102)
    ) transactions     // this subquery alone taking 12 seconds
INNER JOIN
    [HQMatajer].[dbo].[TransactionEntry] transactionsEntry ON transactionsEntry.TransactionNumber = transactions.TransactionNumber 
                                                           AND transactionsEntry.StoreID = transactions.StoreID
INNER JOIN
    [HQMatajer].[dbo].[Item] items ON transactionsEntry.ItemID = items.ID
GROUP BY 
    items.ItemLookupCode
```

Execution plan:

[image: Execution Cost]

Comment: @marc_s Do you know the solution for my problem?

Comment: If there were a quick, obvious solution, I would have posted it .....

Comment: Share your execution plans using [Paste The Plan @ brentozar.com](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/)

Comment: @mohamedfaisal, post your `CREATE TABLE` DDL, including constraints.